# Hide Page/Dialog title on SharePoint Modern List Form

Tags: modern-experience, powerapp, modern-team-site, web-partmodern-w

I'm attempting to hide the "New Item" page title from a Modern SharePoint List.

That title is hidden when the (powerapps) form is accessed from the list. However when accessed directly via url, the title is present.

Has anyone successfully hidden this item?